# Creating a figure listing characteristics of subjects

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg91L.png)

I want to create a figure like that attached where each grid is a participant and then the labeling for rows and columns are characteristics. For this image attached, the figure is displaying characteristics of bacteria isolates. Any ideas of the best way to start?

I have been looking for the best way to tackle this but no luck yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without a look at your data I would suggest to have a look at `geom_tile`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including at least a snippet of your data or some fake data.